# Create a login session based on a referrer

Tags: php, .htaccess, session-state

I have a website "abc.com" that contains information which is only available to the logged in users. There is a registration/login system in place.

However, we need advise on a php code / htaccess or any other method using which if a  user who clicks on our link (abc.com) that is placed on another website xyz.com to be able to bypass the login process and can see all the restricted content.

Once he closes the browser, he then should not be able to access the restricted content.

So essentially creating and maintaining a login session if a user is coming from xyz.com to abc.com and destroying the session once user leaves.

Note: We do not have any control on the third party site xyz.com .. we are only going to provide a link to our website that they will place on their website.

Comment: You could just use some *dynamic* query string parameter with authentication parameter. But I'm afraid it will leak security if not implemented properly though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use http_referer

> http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

```
$_SESSION["referer"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

if ($_SESSION["referer"] == "xyz.com")
{
/*
do some stuff
*/
}
```

Comment: Can the referrer not be spoofed? How secure is this method?

Comment: @MohitSareen no ,, referrer can be spoofed ,, check out http://webdesign.about.com/od/testing/fl/referer-spoofing.htm